# VS Additonal Language Templates

Tags: visual-studio

I normally work in C# but today need to debug some custom code in VB.net from an ssrs report. I want to create a vb.net project to use as a test harness..however my only Installed Templates are for C#. After googling all I can find is a re-install or install the express edition. That doesn't seem to make sense to me as Telerik adds their product as a new language and it shows up fine.

So I would like to have C# & VB.NET under the New Project >> Installed Templates section and thought it would simply mean checking a box in options or copying some files from the install cd to a directory(ies)...???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Express editions of Visual Studio have limited functionality.

If you wish to work with both C# and VB.NET using the Express editions, you need to download and install both versions.

The installer includes the toolchain - the compiler and such, so just getting a project template will not help. Additionally, the IDE for each will only be able to open and work with specific project types.

---

With other editions, you can re-run the installer and select VB.NET as an option. If not originally selected, the compiler and templates wouldn't have been installed.

Comment: I have ultimate via MSDN Ultimate. The GOOGLED solutions recommended adding express.

Comment: @user1278561 - You didn't mention Ultimate. With that, you should just use the installer to add VB.NET support.

Comment: Correct I didn't mention Ultimate and was not very clear. <snip>...OR install express edition...<snip> was perfectly clear in my head but not very specific for others. My apologies for the lack of clarity.